# fs.readFile().toString terminated by empty string

Tags: node.js, buffer, tostring, string-length

the following node script, (wc.js) return a value which is different from the Unix utility wc;

```
fs = require('fs');
//console.log(fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]).toString().split('\n') );
console.log(fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]).toString().split('\n').length );
```

the output on itself, is:

```
vagrant@precise32:~/stuff$ wc -l wc.js
3 wc.js
vagrant@precise32:~/stuff$ node wc.js wc.js
4
```

and by printing the array, seems that the file get's terminated by an extra empty string:

```
vagrant@precise32:~/stuff$ node wc.js wc.js
[ 'fs = require(\'fs\');',
'console.log(fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]).toString().split(\'\\n\') );',
'//console.log(fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]).toString().split(\'\\n\').length );',
'' ]
```

Is it this the expected behavior? I cannot see it reported in the node documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have a trailing newline character at the end of your file?

```
$ node wc.js wc.js
[ 'fs = require(\'fs\');',
  'console.log(fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]).toString().split(\'\\n\') );',
  '// console.log(fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]).toString().split(\'\\n\').length );' ]
```

You can ignore the last newline character with `.replace(/\n$/, '')`, which I believe is the behavior of `wc`.

Comment: the newline gets added when doing the buffer.toString : actually even empty files have extra lines.

    vagrant@precise32:~/stuff$ touch tmpfile
    vagrant@precise32:~/stuff$ node wc.js tmpfile
    1
    vagrant@precise32:~/stuff$ wc -l tmpfile
    0 tmpfile

Comment: I'm pretty sure `buffer.toString()` doesn't add any newline characters. The reason why an empty string returns one line is because if `.split()` doesn't find any matching places to split, it'll return an array with a single element containing the original string, which is, of length 1.

`fs.writeFileSync('tmp', ''); fs.readFileSync('tmp') //<Buffer >`

`fs.writeFileSync('tmp', '\n'); fs.readFileSync('tmp') //<Buffer 0a>`

Comment: > So, it turns out that, according to POSIX, every text file (including Ruby and JavaScript source files) should end with a \n
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/no-newline-at-end-of-file (first duckduckgo result)